# Grails: Issue using remoteFuction and render

Tags: grails, render

I am having issues using remote function updating a second g:select that is based off the selection of the first. I have tried multiple ways and would be willing to change my style to however can get this accomplished.
Following is parts of my attempt
GSP:

```
    <div class="baitSelectionFields">
  <div class ="manufactureSelect">
    <g:select name="manuList" from="${manufactures}" optionValue="name" 
               onclick="${remoteFunction(action: 'loadStyles', update: 'styleSelection')}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="styleSelection" id="styleSelection">
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    styles = Style.findAll()
    for(int i = 0; i<styles.size(); i++){
    println("Worked")
        if(styles.get(i).getActive()==false){
            styles.remove(i)
            i--
        }
    }
    String send = ("<g:select name=\"styleList\" from=\"${styles}\" optionValue=\"name\"/>")
    redner send
```

Any advice or a point in a helpful direction would be awesome. I have been going through grails doc and it really doesnt seem to be helping.
Also here is my error messge
No signature of method: com.manifest.baitCreation.TypeController.redner()

Comment: Should be `render`, not `redner`.

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out a day later. Went back and almost every method i had previously tried worked. Man misspelling can kill. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<g:select />` tag gets rendered server side. You can't send it down as a string. What you may be able to do is `render g.select(name: "styleList", from: styles, optionValue: "name")`